# Flutter group listviews with separator

Tags: flutter

I am looking for some guidance to  create listviews with separators.  For instance, I would like to take messages from a DB grouped by date and separate the messages by date with some graphic or line, etc...  and then have the messages under the separator.  Trying this in flutter and any guidance or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: See also [Flutter divider: How could I add divider between each line in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687633/flutter-divider-how-could-i-add-divider-between-each-line-in-my-code)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I apologize for the ugliness of the design, but just to show you, you can pretty much build your own design that you desire, this a quick example:

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        // itemCount: myData.lenght(),
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            //sort my data by timestamp before building
            return new CustomWidget(date: "Convert my time stamp to date",
              content: "My Awesome Content",
              trailingIconOne: new Icon(Icons.share, color: Colors.blueAccent,),
              trailingIconTwo: new Icon(
                Icons.favorite, color: Colors.redAccent,),);
          }),
    );
  }
}

class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  String date;
  String content;

  Icon trailingIconOne;

  Icon trailingIconTwo;

  CustomWidget(
      {@required this.date, @required this.content, @required this.trailingIconOne, @required this.trailingIconTwo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          border: new Border.all(color: Colors.grey[500])
      ),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container (child: new Text(date), color: Colors.yellow[200],),
          new Container(height: 15.0,),
          new Text(content),
          new Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(icon: trailingIconOne, onPressed: () {}),
              new Container(width: 10.0,),
              new IconButton(icon: trailingIconTwo, onPressed: () {})
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For a better design, you can get rid of the borders and use a `Divider` instead:

```
return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column (children: <Widget>[
            new Container (child: new Text(date), color: Colors.yellow[200],),
            new Container(height: 15.0,),
            new Text(content),
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(icon: trailingIconOne, onPressed: () {}),
                new Container(width: 10.0,),
                new IconButton(icon: trailingIconTwo, onPressed: () {}),
          ], ),

              new Divider(height: 15.0,color: Colors.red,),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
```

And a better visual solution in my opinion is to use a `Card` instead of `Container`,

```
return new Card(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column (children: <Widget>[
            new Container (child: new Text(date), color: Colors.yellow[200],),
            new Container(height: 15.0,),
            new Text(content),
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(icon: trailingIconOne, onPressed: () {}),
                new Container(width: 10.0,),
                new IconButton(icon: trailingIconTwo, onPressed: () {}),
          ], ),

            //  new Divider(height: 15.0,color: Colors.red,),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I think thats enough to get me started in the right direction.  I will post a new item if I get stuck along the way.

Comment: It was not my intention to show a great design anyway, yes Divider is way nicer, but just in this particular layout it needs tweaking to have an effect. I have added the change at the end, probably it would be a better looking design if we use a Card instead of Container as the parent, but this example was only meant to show that you can customize your own widgets.

Comment: Seems I can do this statically without issues, what I need to see the best approach is to pulling the data and sorting . Do I pull the dates and then in each widget after the date divider then pull the messages that go with that date or do I pull all the data and pull out the data for the date I need.  I have this done already as a single listview in date order, but want to convert to having all messages for a particular date below the divider.  Thoughts?  Or should I ask another question on here for an answer?

Comment: Maybe ask another question to make it clearer, in general you would want to store the timestamps within your data item itself, I am not sure if this is clear or not. Another thing, if you are using Firebase rtdb, you can just use `FirebaseAnimatedList` instead of a `ListView` if your data fetching is one layered, and it provides a sorting parameter that you can make use of.

Comment: I am using mysql to store data with a JSON field and generated columns for searchable and indexable fields, customers requirement for DB.  Might be just as easy to call restapi for unique dates and then create divider and then call for the data as the widget is built for the listview of messages for that date.  I will create a question if I get blocked.  Thanks again

Answer (score 29):

simply put the `ListItem` into a `Container` and add decoration:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: new ListTile(
          title: new Text('I have border')
        ),
        decoration:
            new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border(
                    bottom: new BorderSide()
                )
            )
        );
  }
```

Comment: This is much cleaner and easier to follow, imho

Comment: Sure but it puts a border at the bottom of the last element. It's not the right way to do it.

Comment: @Tony Not necessarily "not the right way to do it". If listtiles are looped, check if last index, and not display border. If doing listtile manually, don't add border on last item.

Answer (score 24):

A much cleaner and simple solution would be to use the following

```
ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(child: Text("Index $index")),
      ),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

Long answer short

**Just use `Column` and add `Divider`**

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {return tile(index);},
    ),
```

Create a widget for itemBuilder

```
Widget tile(int index) {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    // your widgets in listView
    Divider(),    //at last simply add divider
  ],
);
```

}

Answer (score 5):

While this might not be applicable to your situation, a simple way to add dividers to a ListView is to use `ListView.divideTiles`:

```
// Adapted from https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#listviews--adapters

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new ListExamplePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ListExamplePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile/divideTiles.html
    var dividedWidgetList = ListTile.divideTiles(
        context: context,
        tiles: _getListData(),
        color: Colors.black).toList();

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('List Example'),
      ),
      body: new ListView(children: dividedWidgetList)
    );
  }

  _getListData() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
      widgets.add(
        new Padding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Text('Row $i'))
      );
    }
    return widgets;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

For dynamically built lists, ListTile.divideTiles isn't the right choice. Adding a divider at the stage where the list item is built is probably the best way to go:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new ListExamplePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ListExamplePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('List Example'),
        ),
        body: new ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) =>
              // Try using either _getRowWithDivider or _getRowWithBoxDecoration
              // for two different ways of rendering a divider
              _getRowWithDivider(position),
        ));
  }

  /// Returns the widget at position i in the list, separated using a divider
  Widget _getRowWithDivider(int i) {
    var children = <Widget>[
      new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: new Text('Row $i')),
      new Divider(height: 5.0),
    ];

    return new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: children,
    );
  }

// Returns the widget at position i in the list, separated using a BoxDecoration
  Widget _getRowWithBoxDecoration(int i) {
    return new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            border:
                new Border(bottom: new BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[100]))),
        child: new Padding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0), child: new Text('Row $i')));
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks promising, how would you proceed if I get my message list via http call, I put it in a list and now I use listview.builder and apply a widget for each item, but now I want a divider by date which could be 1 or many for each date.  I am trying now to do a listview of dividers that has a listview of messages, but battling size errors, etc..  Your solution looks more straightforward accept for the divider needed by date and not each one.  Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: For a dynamic list, ListTile.divideTiles is unfortunately not going to work for you. I'd recommend going with aziza's recommendations and inserting a Divider (or a BoxDecoration) when building the widget per row. I'll update with a different code snippet to demonstrate.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of overly complex answers here

Just use divideTiles:

```
new ListView(
              children: ListTile.divideTiles(context: context, tiles:
```

Or alternatively use separated:

```
new ListView.separated(
              itemCount: 25,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
```

Comment: What about `ListView.builder`?

Answer (score 1):

```
final Iterable<ListTile> products = widget.products.map((Product product) {
  return productListAdapter(
    product: product,
  ).build(context);
});

final listView = ListTile.divideTiles(
        context: context, tiles: products, color: Colors.black12)
    .toList();

return ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0), children: listView);
```

**productListAdapter code is here**

```
class productListAdapter extends StatelessWidget {
   final Product product;  
   productListAdapter({this.product});

   TextStyle getTextStyle() {
       return TextStyle(
           fontSize: 16.0,
           color: Colors.black);
   }

   Color getColor(BuildContext context) {
       return Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
     }
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return ListTile(
       title: Text(product.name),
       leading: CircleAvatar(
         child: Text(
           product.name[0],
           style: getTextStyle(),
         ),
         backgroundColor: getColor(context),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```