# Flutter : How can I add divider between each List Item in my code?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

How could I add divider to list? I use Flutter for Android. I want to add a divider between each List item and I want to colorize the divider and add styles.

I tried to add `new divider();` but I got errors. I also tried `return new divider();`.

Here is the screen shot of my app:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,

          buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
          )
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class Kitten {
  const Kitten({this.name, this.description, this.age, this.imageurl});

  final String name;
  final String description;
  final int age;
  final String imageurl;
}

final List<Kitten> _kittens = <Kitten>[
  Kitten(
      name: "kitchen",
      description: "mehraboon",
      age: 2,
      imageurl:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic- 
      104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=350",
  ),
  Kitten(
      name: "garage",
      description: "khashen",
      age: 1,
      imageurl:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/4602/jumping-cute-playing-animals.jpg? 
      auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=350",
  ),
  Kitten(
      name: "bedroom",
      description: "khar zoor",
      age: 5,
      imageurl:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/978555/pexels-photo-978555.jpeg? 
      auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=350",
  ),
  Kitten(
      name: "living room",
      description: "chorto",
      age: 3,
      imageurl:
      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/209037/pexels-photo-209037.jpeg? 
      auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=350",
  ),
];

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _dialogBuilder(BuildContext context, Kitten kitten) {
    return SimpleDialog(contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, children: [
      Image.network(kitten.imageurl, fit: BoxFit.fill),
      Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child:
          Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
            Text(kitten.name),
            Text('${kitten.age}'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16.0,
            ),
            Text(kitten.description),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Wrap(
                children: [
                  FlatButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const
                  Text("noooo!"),color: Colors.red,),
                  Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),),
                  RaisedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const
                  Text("yesss!"),color: Colors.green)
                ],
              ),
            )
          ]))
    ]);
  }

  Widget _listItemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new GestureDetector(

      onTap: () => showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => _dialogBuilder(context, _kittens[index])),
      child:
      Container(

        padding: EdgeInsets.all( 16.0),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(_kittens[index].name,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),

      ),


    ) ;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Keys"),
        centerTitle: true,


      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _kittens.length,
        itemExtent: 60.0,
        itemBuilder: _listItemBuilder,

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked awesome for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61207011/6665568

Answer (score 358, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do the same thing. Let me compare them here.

## For a short static list

Use `ListTile.divideTiles`

[image]

```
ListView(
  children: ListTile.divideTiles( //          <-- ListTile.divideTiles
      context: context,
      tiles: [
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Horse'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Cow'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Camel'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Sheep'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Goat'),
        ),
      ]
  ).toList(),
)
```

## For a long dynamic list

Use `ListView.separated`.

[image]

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: 100,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('$index sheep'),
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Divider();
  },
)
```

This returns two widgets for every item, except for the last item. The `separatorBuilder` is used to add the divider.

## For adding a divider after the last item

Create a custom item widget that uses a Divider or BoxDecoration.

#### Using Divider

[image]

```
final items = ['Horse', 'Cow', 'Camel', 'Sheep', 'Goat'];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text(items[index]),
          ),
          Divider(), //                           <-- Divider
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

#### Using BoxDecoration

[image]

```
final items = ['Horse', 'Cow', 'Camel', 'Sheep', 'Goat'];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration( //                    <-- BoxDecoration
          border: Border(bottom: BorderSide()),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(items[index]),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Both Divider and BoxDecoration are customizable as far as the line height and color go. Divider also has an indent option, but you could get a BoxDecoration to do the same thing with some padding.

## For more style

Use a Card

[image]

```
final items = ['Horse', 'Cow', 'Camel', 'Sheep', 'Goat'];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card( //                           <-- Card
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(items[index]),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: What about adding divider _before first_ item?

Comment: @AlexSemeniuk, You could use a Divider or BoxDecoration similarly to the example above.

Comment: Unfortunately the example with `ListView.builder` and `Divider` disables (hides) the `onTap` highlight animation.

Answer (score 111):

The most correct way is to use **ListView.separated**

```
ListView.separated(
     itemCount: 25,
     separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1),
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return ListTile(
         title: Text('item $index'),
       );
     },
);
```

Comment: Also, note using ListView.separated last Item won't have the divider you can show it like this

```if (index == itemCount - 1) {  return Divider(height: 1);
                }```

Answer (score 25):

Put your widget inside container with BoxDecoration as

```
Container(
   child: YourWidgetHere(),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.black26))),
);
```

Comment: This enables using Column instead of ListView. Which is useful if you don't want the scrollbar included in ListView.

Answer (score 19):

recently I use this code to set divider:

```
ListView.separated(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text("Hello", style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .primaryColor
          ),),

        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) =>Divider(height: 1, color: Colors.green),
      itemCount: 30),
```

and it works.

For example, I have added my app's screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 15):

On the [flutter getting started tutorial](https://flutter.io/get-started/codelab/) it is covered, the solution they provide is something like this:

```
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: _kittens.length,
    itemExtent: 60.0,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        // Add a one-pixel-high divider widget before each row in theListView.
        if (i.isOdd) return new Divider(color: Colors.purple); // notice color is added to style divider

        return _listItemBuilder();
      },
  ),
  ...
```

That should add the dividers taking into account the odd and even rows to do so.

Also to color the divider pas "color" to the [Divider Class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Divider-class.html):

```
new Divider(color: Colors.purple);
```

Comment: If the itemCount is `_kittens.length` and every other item you are returning a Devider, aren't you going to miss half of the kittens? The getting started tutorial is different than your example.

Comment: The divider is added once for every two otherwise you get two dividers with no kitten between them. The tutorial does cover it as shown in my answer, however they add more to it but it is not needed for it to work. when I tested it, this worked perfectly.

Comment: For this to work you'll need `itemCount: _kittens.length * 2` otherwise yeah you're missing second half of the kittens.

Answer (score 7):

Check out this issue:
[ListView.builder should let clients specify a divider](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12492)
It makes clear that:

1. if you need to build your list with dynamic elements, for now you'll have to deal with this issue on your own. I'd recommend in the row widget building, you include a [List Divider](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Divider-class.html) at the bottom with a column or something, except for the last one (you can test for `index == listData.length - 1`).
2. But if, like in the example you show, you already know all the lists data before hand, or you build it without a `ListView.builder`, then you can and should use the named constructor `ListView.divideTiles`

Answer (score 5):

following [this](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Divider-class.html) Just add Divider() :

```
         Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.network(video["imageUrl"]),
                        Container(
                          height: 6.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          video["name"],
                          textScaleFactor: 1.05,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  )
                ],
              );
```

Comment: Works, but from a performance perspective not optimal.

Answer (score 3):

### Dart 2.3

Another way, especially for generic non-list-view: Using `for` in a Collection ([link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/whats-new-in-dart-2-3-1a7050e2408d)) with the `...` spread operator

```
Column(
   children: [
     for(var i=0; i<4; i+=1)
     ...[Container(height: 100, width: 100),
         Divider()
      ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

The question assumes that we have access to `material.dart` for Android styling (`ListTile` and `Divider`). If you want Cupertino styles, we can:

1. Use a `Column` view wrapper for the row, and add a `Container` with height 1.

   ```
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        row, // A custom Row
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 16,  // Adjust separator left padding.
            right: 16, // Adjust separator right padding.
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: 1,
            color: Styles.productRowDivider, // Custom style
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
   ```
2. The `Divider` is not available in `cupertino.dart`. We can use the same `Container` technique with `ListView.separated`:

   ```
    ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return row;
      },
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
                height: 1,
                color: Styles.productRowDivider, // Custom style
              );
      },
    );
   ```

Comment: One can import both `material.dart` and `cupertino.dart`, and use the former just for `Divider`. This is no overhead because the tree shaking will ensure that only what is used will be included in the release.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, I meant that we need `cupertino.dart` for Cupertino styling.

Answer (score 1):

Thats another way usig Container.

```
 ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text('Home'),
 ),
 Container(height: 1, color: Colors.grey), //divider
 ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
        title: Text('Logout'),
 ),
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to seperate each widget with another widget, except for the last one, this is also an approach:

```dart
Column(
  children: [Container(), Container(), Container()]
      .toList()
      .expand((element) => [element, const SizedBox(height: 16)])
      .toList()
    ..removeLast(),
);
```

Will produce:

- Container()

  - SizedBox()
- Container()

  - SizedBox()
- Container()

Answer (score -2):

Create a Container like this

```
Container(height: 1, color: Colors.grey),
```

And add with your ListTile like this

```
 ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _feed.items.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final item = _feed.items[index];

     return  Column(
         children: <Widget>[
      Container(height: 1, color: Colors.grey),  //Container for devider
      ListTile(                                  //Your tile item
      title: title(item.title),
      subtitle: subtitle(item.pubDate),
      leading: thumbnail(item.enclosure.url),
      trailing: rightIcon(),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      onTap: () => openFeed(item.link),
    )]);
  },
);
```

Now you can see final output in my screenshot

[image]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZuIg.jpg

Comment: If you are going to use `ListView.builder`, you might as well replace it with `ListView.separated`. That way, you can pass a new `IndexedWidgetBuilder` on `separatorBuilder` and build your divider there.