# How to use divideTiles() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a ListView with dividers between each ListTile.
I saw that there is a static method to do that called divideTiles() but i did not understand how to use that.. How/where is this function used?

My code is a simple ListView with ListTiles as children.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
ListView(
  children: ListTile.divideTiles(
    context: context,
    tiles: [
      // your widgets here
    ]
  ).toList(),
)
```

Alternatively you can go with `ListView.separated`:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: 42,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    // your widget here 
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Divider(); 
  },
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a supplemental answer that shows what the divider looks like:

[image]

```
ListView(
  children: ListTile.divideTiles(
      context: context,
      tiles: [
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Horse'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Cow'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Camel'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Sheep'),
        ),
        ListTile(
          title: Text('Goat'),
        ),
      ]
  ).toList(),
)
```

From [here](https://medium.com/@studymongolian/a-complete-guide-to-flutters-listtile-597a20a3d449)

Comment: This works well - any idea how to ensure there is also a divider after the last tile?

Comment: @vikzilla Use a `ListView.builder()` with a `Divider`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384027/3681880) for an example.

Comment: How can I increase the thickness of the divider using divideTiles?

Comment: @ScottF, See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384027/3681880). I'd use a `ListView.builder` with your own custom divider.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using listview you can go with this alternate

```
ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){
    return ListTile(title: new Column(children: <Widget>[
      new Text('Hello how are you?'),
      new Divider(height: 20.0,)// add value for height or leave it blank for default
    ],) );
  })
```

Comment: Before the answer of this question i used Divider with normal ListView (not builder) and it worked fine. I wanted to use DivideTiles because the doc says it is a better way! But thanks anyway :)