# space between divider and container in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The divider is not adjusting as I need, All the stuff inside in Column Widget and not able to set vertical line.

```
 Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[300]),
        child:
       Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
         mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
         children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(child: TextFormField(
             style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
             decoration: InputDecoration(
               border: InputBorder.none,
               prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.grey,size: 30.0,),
               hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 18.0),
               hintText: 'Search',
             ),),),

           IconButton(onPressed:(){},icon: Image.asset('assets/images/grid.png',fit: BoxFit.contain ,),),
           Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),width: 5.0,child: Text(''),),
           IconButton(onPressed:(){},icon: Image.asset('assets/images/list.png',fit: BoxFit.contain ,),),

         ],
       )),
       Divider(color: Colors.grey,),
```

I need this 
[image]

and getting this

[image]

Comment: Wrap container to Expanded widget or Play with mainAxis size of Column.

Comment: Simple flawless solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61207011/6665568 :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah the `Divider` will always have padding so I just recreated what you wanted using `BoxDecoration`s instead:

[image: image of design]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Material(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[300]),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        size: 30.0,
                      ),
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 18.0),
                      hintText: 'Search',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor), left: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor)),
                ), child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.view_list), onPressed: () {},)),
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor), left: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor)),
                ), child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.view_list), onPressed: () {},)),
              ],
            )),

      ])),
    );
  }
```

Edit: reuploaded pic for clarity and removed width of borders so stays as default 1.0.

Comment: I think it draws border as rectangle not for single bottom line.

Comment: You have `border: InputBorder.none` set in your `InputDecoration` of your `TextFormField` which I removed. Have you done that?

Answer (score 103):

Just give a height of `1` to the divider.

```
Divider(height: 1)
```

This will remove any padding it has.

**Full code below :**

```
ListView.separated(
     itemCount: 10,
     separatorBuilder: (_ , __ ) => Divider(height:1),
     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
       return ListTile(
         title: Text('item $index'),
       );
     },
);
```

Answer (score 14):

Just remove divider replace with this line

```
      Container(color: Colors.grey, height: 1)
```

and set Column

```
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
```

Answer (score 5):

The appropriate padding is automatically computed from the height. So, setting height of divider to 0 will remove the padding.