# Flutter Listview.Separated add Separator at beginning and end of list

Tags: flutter, dart

Using flutter, what is the easiest and cleanest way to place a separator not only between the rows, but also as the first and last row ?

I am able to do so by faking the `itemCount` and adding to extra rows.

```
...
child: ListView.separated(
  // Offset itemCount to start with separator
  itemCount: sortedList.length + 2,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0) {
      return SizedBox(height: 0.0);
    }
    if (index == sortedList.length + 1) {
      return SizedBox(height: 0.0);
    }
    return ListItem(...);
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return SizedBox(height: 10.0);
  }))),
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid this is as clean as we can get with `ListView.separated`

```dart
ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(height: 1.0,),
  itemCount: 2 + boardList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == 0 || index == boardList.length + 1) return const SizedBox.shrink();
    return MenuItem(
      board: boardList[index - 1], 
      isSelected: boardList[index].id == selectedBoardId
    );
  },
);
```

Another way is to use `ListView.builder` and wrap your item a `container` with border bottom

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: boardList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: (widget.isSelected) ? Colors.grey[50] : color,
        border: Border(
          top: (index == 0) ? BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor) : BorderSide.none
          bottom: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor)
          
        )
      )
    ),
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `ListView.serarated` in another `ListView` and then put your Dividers before and after the `ListView.separated`. But you need to define the `scrollDirection` and `shrinkWrap` as shown in the example. Otherwise, you will get an error for unbounded hight. As separators, I used the Divider-Widget but you can use whatever you want.

```
ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Divider(),
          ListView.separated(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: // ...
            separatorBuilder: // ...
            itemCount: // ...
          ),
          Divider(),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Yeah that's another way to do it, but performance-wise isn't it completely overkill?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I found something else, look at the first answer and then scroll down to "For adding a divider after the last item": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687633/flutter-divider-how-could-i-add-divider-between-each-line-in-my-code

Answer (score 1):

Or make `itemBuilder` return a `Column` with your list item in between 2 conditional separators.

```
ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
  itemCount: list.length,
  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        if (index == 0)
          const Divider(),
        ListItem(
          index: index,
        ),
        if (list.length == index + 1)
          const Divider()
      ],
    );
  }),
)
```