# Add separator to ListTile

Tags: flutter

I would like to include separators in my list, but my _buildTenableListTile() function returns a ListTile().

How can I do to be able to include the separator in my list?

```
  Widget _buildReorderableListSimple(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      onReorder: _onReorder,
      children: _getListItems(),
    );
  }

  List<ListTile> _getListItems() => _items
      .asMap()
      .map((i, item) => MapEntry(i, _buildTenableListTile(item, i)))
      .values
      .toList();

  ListTile _buildTenableListTile(Song item, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      key: ValueKey(item.songId),
      title: new Text(
        '${item.sequence}. ${item.name}',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: new Text(
        '${item.artist} ${item.songId}',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {

      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `_getListItems` to something like this:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: _items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return _buildTenableListTile(_items[index],index);
  },
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Divider();
  },
)
```

Comment: type 'ListView' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Comment: _getListItems() {
    return ListView.separated(
        itemCount: _items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _buildTenableListTile(_items[index], index);
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider();
        });
  }

Comment: The ReorderableListView widget receives a List, not a ListView.

Comment: @AlexandreMarques ok check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687633/flutter-divider-how-could-i-add-divider-between-each-line-in-my-code)