# Flutter ListWheelScrollView , How to add horizontal lines

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

This is flutter_datetime_picker's UI. How to add horizontal lines like this:

[image]

This is my code and UI.

```
ListWheelScrollView(
  itemExtent: 20,
  diameterRatio: 0.9,
  perspective: 0.003,
  controller: dayScrollController,
  physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(
    parent: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  ),
  children: dayList.map((item) {
    return Container(
      height: 20,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
          '$item',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: dayList.indexOf(item) != dayIndex ? Colors.grey : Colors.black,
            fontSize: 20
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }).toList(),
  onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
    setState(() {
      dayIndex = index;
    });
  },
),
```

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687633/flutter-divider-how-could-i-add-divider-between-each-line-in-my-code) could maybe help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`CupertinoPicker`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html) widget, which looks like this:

[image: CupertinoPicker demo image]

Or if you want to make a widget for selecting date and time, you can also use [`CupertinoDatePicker`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html) widget, which looks like this:

[image: CupertinoDatePicker demo image]

For more Cupertino (iOS-style) widgets, check out this page: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino

Answer (score 0):

try adding these two lines as properties under ListWheelScrollView:

```
useMagnifier: true,
magnification: 1.2,
```

or use `CupertinoPicker`